# .htaccess rewrite rules for www.example.com and example.com -> this.example.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I would like my site to direct all traffic from www.example.com and example.com or anythingelse.example.com to **this.example.com** This is what I have in my .htaccess file which is located in /www/example.com/public_html directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://this.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

It works when I visit this.example.com but when I visit http://example.com it redirects me to example.com/public_html and www.example.com doesn't redirect at all! However this.example.com works. This is my virtual host setting:

```
<VirtualHost 12.34.56.78:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
 ServerName example.com
 ServerAlias this.example.com
 ServerAlias www.example.com
 DocumentRoot /srv/www/example.com/public_html/
 ErrorLog /srv/www/example.com/logs/error.log
 CustomLog /srv/www/example.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I've noticed in my error log when I visit: example.com it says "File does not exist: /srv/www/example.com/public_html/public_html"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution provided by requinix on [devshed](http://forums.devshed.com/apache-development-15/subdomain-rewrite-example-com-to-this-example-com-815484.html)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !this.example.com
RewriteRule ^ http://this.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```